# bootstrap navigation bar autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap. I added a Google autocomplete to an input box. But autocomplete is appearing under the navigation bar.

[image]

css file is here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Place Search
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Places</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input class="input-xlarge" id="searchBox" type="text">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn dropdown-toggle">S</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Just giving us the HTML is not going to do it. The CSS is the problem, please update your post to include the CSS.

Comment: bootstrap is http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: So there is no custom css?

Comment: I don't think a lot of people are going to download it and then look at the CSS, just include the bits we need so we can look at it on here. I don't use any programs to look at other peoples code. I just look on here and try to help where I can and I'm sure a lot of other people do that too. We also have no idea if you have edited the CSS at all, because 1 missing character could cause problems within CSS.

Comment: I did not edit bootstrap css file. It is original.

Comment: @youtubeline if you add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demostrating your problem then you might attract some more answers

Comment: everybody knows bootstrap & where to find it's CSS :P anyways, I have the same issue. The "navbar-top-fixed" has a z-index of "1030", so obviously google autocomplete has a lower value. Not sure how to add the z-index to the google places autocomplete drop-down

Answer (score 0):

```
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:relative;z-index:99">
            <li><a href="#">Places</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something 2</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Use `position:relative;z-index:99`